# Why the solution of the following IVP is the trivial solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I have a question about the following example. It is about the Peano Uniqueness Theorem.

[image]

Why is the only solution the trivial one? Couldn't we just use the separate variables method and get another solution? I don't understand it very well, any help is welcome!

Comment: Note $y(x)=0$ is a solution to your IVP. Have you looked at what Theorem 1.3.1 says? If the hypotheses of Theorem 1.3.1 are satisfied, and if the conclusion of Theorem 1.3.1 guarantees the uniqueness of a solution, then you know $y\equiv 0$ must be the only solution.